# Securing Crystal Reports using Parameter Fields , Validating Parameter Fields

Tags: c#, security, validation, crystal-reports, parameters

Can a password be set as parameter field in a Crystal Report , OR, could Validations be applied on a parameter field of a Crystal Report, like , if the user enters the wrong parameter , then the report quits?

Comment: Are you trying to secure the database access or secure columns and rows once data has been retrieved?

Comment: @craig-the columns and rows once the data has been retrieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the report quit/exit, but you can definitely hide details/groups/records in a report if the parameter is incorrect.

If they are using Crystal Reports, they can open the report and remove your "password protection", but yes, you can do some pseudo protection if the report is being run in a viewer of some type.

All you would do is create a parameter called {?Password}. Then, within your current record selection, put:

```
(your previous record selection) AND {?Password} = "yourpassword"
```

This logic works like any other SQL logic in that the query must be true to return records. In the case above, if the password does not match, the query is false.

That would keep any records from showing up.

Alternatively, you can hide/suppress sections based on similar logic or even show a section if the password is wrong (and hide it if it's right). Within this logic, you could format a section to show "Invalid Password Entered" if the password is wrong.

Make sense?

Comment: sir, please tell me what does this mean----"(your previous record selection)"

Comment: @sqlchild - it just means whatever his previous (current) record selection is/was. If his previous record selection was "foo=foo" then his new record selection would be "(foo=foo) AND {?Password} = 'yourpassword'

Comment: sir,how i would get the value of the previous record? when the report will open for the first time, then only i want that it asks for the password parameter? please help me with the steps i had to perform in Crystal Reports and with the code too....would be a great help sir.

Comment: @sqlchild - Crystal parameters are prompted each time a report is run. If you keep Crystal open, you can reuse parameters, but there's not a way to ask for password parameter just once. It sounds like you need more than just a report password. You should check out using a commercial viewer (like the ones on http://www.ReportRunner.com)